# This is a crossudoku

Tags: sudoku

So, this is a crossudoku.

It is the same as a sudoku - same rules apply. However, you have been given crossword-like clues for part of the numbers on the grid.

Some of the clues may have multiple answers - so you may need to be solving the "crossnumber" and the "sudoku" part of the puzzle simultaneously to find the correct digit for each cell.

[image]

**A1-C1** and **C9-E9** Then will I swear beauty herself is black,
And all they foul that thy complexion lack.

**A2-B2, I5-I6, I7-I9** and **B6-B8** A perfect square and a perfect cube

**A5-G5** A quick and easy approximation of a pie

**E3-F3** The answer.

**F2-G2** and **G4-H4**  The number of months in a year

**G6-H6, G7-H7, C6-D6** and **B9-C9** The sum of two consecutive squares

**D4-E4,  H1-H2** and **I6-I7** There is a lot of silver lining hidden in this grid...

**E8-H8** My kingdom is not of this world.

**C7-D7** The sum of two consecutive cubes

**A4-A7** The devil was hit by a cube

**B5-B8** Your ride when you are drunk

**I8-I9** The sum of 3 consecutive squares

**I3-I4** Some buildings skip this floor

**F3-F4** and **G2-G3** Between a square and a cube

Comment: Is the pie definitely A5-G5 rather than A5-F5?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Yes, it is A5-G5

Comment: I believe I know what is intended by the devil clue. Would you like me to tell you?

Comment: Does a hint corespond to only one nulber ? eg: The sum of two consecutive squares ? Is this always the same number ?

Comment: ah, and I think I now know what A5-G5 is meant to be. But, alas, clearly I'm losing the race :-).

Comment: @Skyvask, considering the fact that G6-H6 and G7-H7 couldn't be the same by the rules of sudoku, the answer to this question is "No, it is not always the same number." :) Sometimes, it is. But not always.

Comment: Excellent puzzle. Simply beautiful. The fact that you would have to solve every clue given to get the final answer is what makes this puzzle an amazing one for me.

Comment: Interestingly you don't need clues 3 or 11.  I wonder if there are others you could have left out and leave this solvable.  You do need the devil hit by a cube.

Comment: @kaine, I actually like 3 and 11 - these were the ones I started with. :) Also, they help reaffirm the solver that the solution is correct. :)

Comment: @MariaDeleva I thought the puzzle was a little on the easy side so removing some would be the way to make it more challenging.  I really liked number 3 and understood quickly what it meant but chose not to use it. I didn't get #11 until after it was solved. I'd sooner remove some duplicate silver, month, or cube/square ones.

Comment: @kaine, well, I will have this in mind next time. :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The filled grid looks like this:

> [image]

Several of the clues have only a single possibility considering that we know the number of digits and that all digits have to be unique. The second clue especially gives a little of information. Starting with around half of the clues entered into the grid and solving with the sudoku rules we can slowly decipher the other clues and solve the whole grid.

#### The solution to the clues are:

**A1-C1** and **C9-E9** Then will I swear beauty herself is black,
And all they foul that thy complexion lack.

> 132 (Sonnet 132 by Shakespeare)

**A2-B2, I5-I6, I7-I9** and **B6-B8** A perfect square and a perfect cube

> 64, 64, 729, 729 (64 and 729 are the only perfect squares and cubes with 2 or 3 digits)

**A5-G5** A quick and easy approximation of a pie

> 3142857 (22/7 is a approximation of pi, whose first digits are 3.142857)

**E3-F3** The answer.

> 42 (The answer to everything)

**F2-G2** and **G4-H4**  The number of months in a year

> 12

**G6-H6, G7-H7, C6-D6** and **B9-C9** The sum of two consecutive squares

> 85, 41, 61, 61 (Possibilities are 13, 25, 41, 61, 85)

**D4-E4,  H1-H2** and **I6-I7** There is a lot of silver lining hidden in this grid...

> 47 (Atomic number of silver (thanks Lolgast))

**E8-H8** My kingdom is not of this world.

> 1836 (Quote from John 18:36 (thanks Lolgast))

**C7-D7** The sum of two consecutive cubes

> 35 (35, 91 are the possibilities)

**A4-A7** The devil was hit by a cube

> 5328 (8 * 666)

**B5-B8** Your ride when you are drunk

> 1729 (Taxicab numbers)

**I8-I9** The sum of 3 consecutive squares

> 29 (14, 29, 50, 77 are the possibilities; the clue is not needed because of the second clue)

**I3-I4** Some buildings skip this floor

> 13 (Some buildings skip the 13th floor because of superstition)

**F3-F4** and **G2-G3** Between a square and a cube

> 26 (Lies between 25 and 27, the only number to do so with 2 digits)

Comment: Damn it, I was like 5 seconds short of getting my answer in :-). Curse you, Actual Work! (Good solve, w l. Upvoted.)

Comment: This is correct. :) It would be nice, if you could also list the answers to the clues with some short explanation of the solution. :) If and when you have the time. :)

Comment: @MariaDeleva Was already doing that, but had to answer before Gareth had a chance!

Comment: My kingdom is not of this world is a quoate from John 18:36 from the bible. 47 is the atomic number of silver.

Comment: Arf, missing to much clue, specially with the taxi number, shakespear, but nice work :)

Comment: I seem to recall 26 and 0 are the only two numbers to be between a square and a cube.