# This is a crossudoku 2

Tags: sudoku

As a follow-up to the first [This is a crossudoku](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/57456/this-is-a-crossudoku) puzzle, I decided to make a new one.

[image]

Here are the clues:

**Horizontal:**

**D2-F2** The sum of three consecutive prime numbers
**B3-E3, F9-I9** A novel by George Orwell
**A5-C5** Number of countries in the world
**H5-I5** The number of minutes an iguana can stay under water
**A6-B6** Bones in your foot
**B7-C7** Giraffe tongue in inches
**B7-G7** Number of litres of fuel a Boeing 747 airliner can hold

**Vertical**

**B3-B6** Longest street in km (or the popular misconception for it)
**D2-D5** Braille alphabet was invented
**D6-D8** The number of octominoes
**C1-C3, G7-G9** A cube of a square
**H1-H2** A square
**H3-H4** Ga
**I2-I4** A square

Comment: B3-E3 is the novel, B3-B6 is the street length (or, as it turns out, a popular misconception for it :) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not 100% sure I have it nailed, but I got down to one...

> Horizontal:
>
>  D2-F2 The sum of three consecutive prime numbers - since D2 is $1$ from Braille clue and E3 is $4$ from Orwell clue, $159$, $173$, or $187$ - say **1AB**
>  B3-E3, F9-I9 A novel by George Orwell - $1984$
>  A5-C5 Number of countries in the world - $195$ (according to the U.N.)
>  H5-I5 The number of minutes an iguana can stay under water - $30$ ($0$ can't be right and can't start with $3$ due to Ga) - say **2C**
>  A6-B6 Bones in your foot - $26$
>  B7-C7 Giraffe tongue in inches - I found "$18$-$20$" but a leading $1$ contradicts Braille as $1824$, so $21$?
>  B7-G7 Number of litres of fuel a Boeing 747 airliner can hold - I've seen reference to $216,000$ litres (fits with giraffe $21$ and the $6$ of octominoes), G7 is $7$ from "cube of a square" - say **216DE7**
>
>  Vertical:
>
>  B3-B6 Longest street in km  (or the popular misconception for it) - Yonge Street $1896$
>  D2-D5 Braille alphabet was invented - $1824$
>  D6-D8 The number of octominoes - $369$
>  C1-C3, G7-G9 A cube of a square - No six digit ones work, so $729$
>  H1-H2 A square - disregarding $3$, $1$, and $8$ from all: $25$, $49$, or $64$ - say **FG**
>  H3-H4 Ga - Gallium, atomic number $31$
>  I2-I4 A square - disregarding $2$ and $1$ from I2, $1$, $9$, $8$, $4$, and $3$ from I3, $8$, $2$, and $1$ from I4, and $4$ from all places: $529$, $576$, $625$, or $729$ - say **HIJ**

This gives:

> ```
>  
>      A B C   D E F   G H I
>    +-------+-------+-------+
>  1 | · · 7 | · · · | · F · |
>  2 | · · 2 | 1 A B | · G H |
>  3 | · 1 9 | 8 4 · | · 3 I |
>    +-------+-------+-------+
>  4 | · 8 · | 2 · · | · 1 J |
>  5 | 1 9 5 | 4 · · | · 2 C |
>  6 | 2 6 · | 3 · · | · · · |
>    +-------+-------+-------+
>  7 | · 2 1 | 6 D E | 7 · · |
>  8 | · · · | 9 · · | 2 · · |
>  9 | · · · | · · 1 | 9 8 4 |
>    +-------+-------+-------+
> ```
>
> ...and a single solution that fits all of the constraints I placed on values **A**,**B**,**C**,**F**,**G**,**H**,**I**, and **J**:
>
> ```
>  
>      A B C   D E F   G H I
>    +-------+-------+-------+
>  1 | 8 3 7 | 5 9 6 | 1 4 2 |
>  2 | 6 4 2 | 1 7 3 | 8 9 5 |
>  3 | 5 1 9 | 8 4 2 | 6 3 7 |
>    +-------+-------+-------+
>  4 | 7 8 3 | 2 5 9 | 4 1 6 |
>  5 | 1 9 5 | 4 6 7 | 3 2 8 |
>  6 | 2 6 4 | 3 1 8 | 5 7 9 |
>    +-------+-------+-------+
>  7 | 9 2 1 | 6 8 4 | 7 5 3 |
>  8 | 4 7 8 | 9 3 5 | 2 6 1 |
>  9 | 3 5 6 | 7 2 1 | 9 8 4 |
>    +-------+-------+-------+
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Oh ... there seems to be a guess already ... that's why even though I'm not done yet I'll share my work so far.

--- After edit ---

Now here's my solution

**Horizontal:**

D2-F2 The sum of three consecutive prime numbers

> First there was a eight options but the Braille clue gave away that the number starts with **1** so the prime numbers left to consider were *29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71*.
>  They make up eight sums: *109, 121, 131, 143, 159, 173, 187, 199*
>  Of these sums  can be easily dismissed since they contain double numbers or zeroes leaving us with: *143, 159, 173, 187*
>  The Orwell clue rules out the options containing 4 or 8. What's left: *159, 173*
>  Further sudokuing (is that a word?) reveals a number 5 in the square ruling out *159* and leaving us with ***173*** as answer

B3-E3, F9-I9 A novel by George Orwell

> Quick googling reveals ***1984***

A5-C5 Number of countries in the world

> *193* if we count UN-countries only, *195* if we count the other two, but the digits ***19...*** are definite. After some consideration ... it kind of says **all** countries, therefore ***195*** must be the answer.

H5-I5 The number of minutes an iguana can stay under water

> Googling says 30 but that cannot be true since 0 is not a number found in Sudokus, numbers higher than 30 don't make much sense when googling, so a leading ***2...*** seems plausible but I left that open for now since that is not definite.
>  Since *26, 27 and 29* can be ruled out by sudokuing and the number has to be at least close to *30*, the solution to this one must be ***28***

A6-B6 Bones in your foot

> ***26*** definite answer

B7-C7 Giraffe tongue in inches

> Google says 18 - 20 inches, which means 18 or 19, since 20 contains a zero. However, the **747 clue** gives away that it really must be ***21*** even though I didn't find that info during research.

B7-G7 Number of litres of fuel a Boeing 747 airliner can hold

> I found online that there are several types of Boeing 747 which have different fuel capacities that begin with a leading 1 or 2. But the **longest road clue** gives away that it cannot be 1, so there is two types left. The numbers given by the **cube of square clue** and the **octomino clue** rule out the larger one leaving ***216847*** as definite result.

**Vertical**

B3-B6 Longest street in km (or the popular misconception for it)

> Guiness World Records listed Yonge Street for some time but it only has 56km. However, a common misconception said that its length was ***1896*** km which must be the answer

D2-D5 Braille alphabet was invented

> ***1824***, easy, look it up

D6-D8 The number of octominoes

> Definite mathematical thing -> definite answer: ***369***

C1-C3, G7-G9 A cube of a square

> The only cube of a square with three digits: ***729***

H1-H2 A square

> Possbile two digit squares: *16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81*
>  We can rule out 81 with the *Orwille clue* an 25 with the *Iguana clue* having now *16, 36, 49, 64* left as guesses.
>  Some further sudokuing and the *1* from the **Ga clue** rule out every number with a *1* and a *6*: *16, 36, 64*, conveniently leaving ***49*** as final answer.

H3-H4 Ga

> This could be a reference to Gallium, which would be *31* on the periodic table.
>  This could also be numerically encoded, resulting in *71*
>  Having only this two clues I dare make the conclusion, that the second digit is *...1*.
> > Having *576* as three digit square rules out *71* leaving ***31*** as answer.

I2-I4 A square

> There are a total of 22 possible three digit squares but ruling them out with the rules of Sudoku left me with: *529, 576, 625 and 691*
>  Getting *49* in the **double digit square clue** rules out *691*, leaving *529, 576 and 625*
>  Some sudokuing after guessing the *country clue* we get *6* as definite last digit and therefore ***576*** as answer.

After having solved all clues everything left was to solve the Sudoku which went astoundingly fast.

My solution looks as follows

> --------+-------+--------
>      | 8 3 7 | 5 9 6 | 1 4 2 |
>      | 6 4 2 | 1 7 3 | 8 9 5 |
>      | 5 1 9 | 8 4 2 | 6 3 7 |
>      --------+-------+--------
>      | 7 8 3 | 2 5 9 | 4 1 6 |
>      | 1 9 5 | 4 6 7 | 3 2 8 |
>      | 2 6 4 | 3 1 8 | 5 7 9 |
>      --------+-------+--------
>      | 9 2 1 | 6 8 4 | 7 5 3 |
>      | 4 7 8 | 9 3 5 | 2 6 1 |
>      | 3 5 6 | 7 2 1 | 9 8 4 |
>      --------+-------+--------

Comment: See the <pre><code> markup trick I used to format my sudoku. EDIT maybe with only 46 you can't see, so I've edited it in for you.

Comment: Seems like I have overwritten your EDIT when finishing my solution. However it is now also readable.